# Will a polymorphic object that has been cast to an derived type have the same reference value

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Say I have:

```
class Foo { }

class Bar : Foo { }
```

And an instantiated object of type `Bar` called `polly`, which is a member of a `List<Foo>`, will `List<Foo>.Contains(polly)` return true, or false?

And secondly, does an object maintain the same reference when referred as the base class and the derived class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Down- or up-casting does not change the reference and memory address. It just changes the way compiler allows you to interact with that object.

```
> string fooString = "test"; ;
> object fooObject = fooString;
> bool areSameReference = object.ReferenceEquals(fooString, fooObject);
> areSameReference
true
```

So the answer to second question is **yes**.

The first question will also be a **yes**, assuming `Foo` does not implement custom comparison logic as `List<T>.Contains` uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` which will fallback to `ObjectEqualityComparer<T>` and reference-based comparison only if nothing else is possible.

Comment: It would be very bad if a class would implement a custom comparison that would not result in equality for the same reference.